# Animaciones de Use Animations no funcionan

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Estoy haciendo un **Footer** con iconos animados con la libreria `react-useanimations` para acceso a Redes Sociales. Por alguna razón en algunos proyectos de **Nextjs** funcionan y en otros simplemente no funcionan. Alguien puede echarme una luz sobre este tema?

[Documentacion](https://react.useanimations.com/)

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]